# How to check when is the last time S3 bucket has been updated?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, aws-cli

Does S3 bucket has information in regard to when is the last time it has been updated? How can I find the last time *any* of the objects in the bucket were updated?

Answer (score 12):

There is **no native support** for bucket `last modified time`. The way I do it is to use `aws cli` , sort the output, take the bottom line and print the first 2 fields.

```
$ aws s3 ls mybucket --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f1,2
2016-03-18 22:46:48
```

Answer (score 9):

## Recommendation, tl;dr

The best compromise for a simple command that is performant, at the time of this writing based on the simplistic performance test, would be `aws s3 ls --recursive` (Option #2)

---

## 3 ways to get the last modified object

### 1. Using `s3cmd`

(See [s3cmd Usage](https://s3tools.org/usage), or explore the man page after [installing](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/blob/master/INSTALL#L36) it using `sudo pip install s3cmd` )

```
s3cmd ls s3://the-bucket | sort| tail -n 1
```

---

### 2. Using AWS CLI's `s3`

```
aws s3 ls the-bucket --recursive --output text | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1"T"$2","$3","$4}'
```

(Note that `awk` in the above refers to GNU awk. See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities?answertab=votes#tab-top) if you need to install this, as well as for any other GNU utilities on macOS)

---

### 3. Using AWS CLI's `s3api`

(with either [`list-objects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html) or [`list-objects-v2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html))

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket the-bucket | jq  -r '.[] | max_by(.LastModified) | [.Key, .LastModified, .Size]|@csv'
```

Note that both of the `s3api` commands are paginated and handling the pagination is a [fundamental improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534077/what-is-the-difference-between-boto3-list-objects-and-list-objects-v2/37539994) in `v2` of the list-objects.

If the bucket has more than a 1000 objects (use `s3cmd du "s3://ons-dap-s-logs" | awk '{print $2}'` to get the number of objects), then you'll need to handle pagination of the API and make multiple calls to get back all the results since the [sort order](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html) of the returned results is `UTF-8 binary order`  and not 'Last Modified'.

---

### Performance comparison

Here is a simple performance comparison of the above three methods executed for the same bucket. For simplicity, the bucket had less than a 1000 objects. Here is the one-liner to see the execution times:

```
export bucket_name="the-bucket" && \
( \
time ( s3cmd     ls --recursive           "s3://${bucket_name}"             | awk '{print $1"T"$2","$3","$4}' | sort | tail -n 1                       ) & ; \
time ( aws s3    ls --recursive           "${bucket_name}"    --output text | awk '{print $1"T"$2","$3","$4}' | sort | tail -n 1                       ) & ; \
time ( aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "${bucket_name}"                  | jq  -r '.[] | max_by(.LastModified) | [.LastModified, .Size, .Key]|@csv' ) & ; \
time ( aws s3api list-objects    --bucket "${bucket_name}"                  | jq  -r '.[] | max_by(.LastModified) | [.LastModified, .Size, .Key]|@csv' ) &
) >! output.log
```

(`output.log` will store the last modified objects listed by each command)

The output of the above is as follows:

```
( s3cmd ls --recursive ...)      1.10s user 0.10s system 79% cpu 1.512 total
( aws s3 ls --recursive ...)     0.72s user 0.12s system 74% cpu 1.128 total
( aws s3api list-objects-v2 ...) 0.54s user 0.11s system 74% cpu 0.867 total
( aws s3api list-objects ...)    0.57s user 0.11s system 75% cpu 0.900 total
```

For the same number of objects being returned, `aws s3api` calls are appreciably more performant; however, there is the additional (scripting) complexity for dealing with the pagination of the API.

Useful link(s):
See [Leveraging s3 and s3api](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/leveraging-the-s3-and-s3api-commands/) to understand the difference between `aws s3` and `aws s3api`

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, there's no magic bit of metadata that stores this information. You just have to loop over the objects.

Code to do that with [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html):

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

def bucket_last_modified(bucket_name: str) -> datetime:
    """
    Given an S3 bucket, returns the last time that any of its objects was
    modified, as a timezone-aware datetime.
    """
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    objects = list(bucket.objects.all())
    return max(obj.last_modified for obj in objects)
```

Comment: Hi what if I want to get the filename which has the last_modified time?

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to write a bucket_metadata.json file to the bucket with a "last_updated" key and a unix timestamp:

```
{ "last_updated": 1634243586 }
```

Then whenever you update the bucket, you generate another timestamp and re-write the file.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging aggregation feature of the `aws s3api` commmand, you can easily get some key metrics via:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "bucket_name" --output json --query "[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[]), max(Contents[].LastModified)]"
```

If the bucket is empty, the aggregations fail due to null values, and you will receive an error message: `In function sum(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array-number'], received: "null"`

If the bucket is too large, your command might get killed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bash script and python script can do the job, but I find that it quiet slow when the S3 bucket have millions objects, So if anyone can improve the script would be great.
Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

bucket_name_list=$(aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name" --output text)
for bucket_name in $bucket_name_list
do
    # echo $bucket_name
    last_access_time=$(aws s3 ls $bucket_name --recursive --output text | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1"T"$2","$3","$4}')
    echo "${bucket_name}: ------->  ${last_access_time}"
done
```

Python:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime


aws_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='default')
s3_resource = aws_session.resource('s3')

def bucket_last_modified() -> datetime:
    
    for s3_bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
        s3_bucket_name = s3_bucket.name
        bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(s3_bucket_name)
        objects = list(bucket.objects.all())
        if len(objects) != 0:
            last_access_time = max(obj.last_modified for obj in objects)
            print('Bucket Name: ' + s3_bucket_name + ' last access time: ' + str(last_access_time))
        else:
            print('Bucket Name: ' + s3_bucket_name + ' is empty')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
  bucket_last_modified()
```

Answer (score -1):

Amazon S3 API spec on GET BUCKET Object Versions (available at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETVersion.html) says that there's LastModified property returned - but I'm not sure if it get's updated on change for each object ...

Comment: This isn't the answer to the question that was asked.  `LastModified`: "Date and time the *object* was last modified." This property is returned for *each individual object version*.  It is not a single value for the bucket itself.

Comment: Yes, you are right - so I guess the only way is to recursively scan the whole subtree ... might be expensive