# shell script - AWS s3 bucket, find last added file

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get last added file in AWS s3 bucket using linux shell script. 
Can you anyone let me know how I can do this job?

Comment: Anything you have tried you can show us? Preferably with exact error message or problem description? Can you explain what an S3 "bucket" is? Is it a directory?

Comment: A small tip if you are allowed to use it: use timestamp as the header for the file name and sort files when query them.For example: 1939847568_my_file_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the output of [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) and `sort` the output to get the last added file.

```
s3cmd ls s3://{{bucket}} | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

- `sort` - sorts the output by creation time
- `tail -n 1` - returns the last file
- `awk '{print $2}'` - prints the file name

Answer (score 1):

## Recommendation, tl;dr

The best compromise for a simple command that is performant, at the time of this writing based on the simplistic performance test, would be `aws s3 ls --recursive` (Option #2)

---

## 3 ways to get the last modified object

### 1. Using `s3cmd`

(See [s3cmd Usage](https://s3tools.org/usage), or explore the man page after [installing](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/blob/master/INSTALL#L36) it using `sudo pip install s3cmd` )

```
s3cmd ls s3://the-bucket | sort| tail -n 1
```

---

### 2. Using AWS CLI's `s3`

```
aws s3 ls the-bucket --recursive --output text | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1"T"$2","$3","$4}'
```

(Note that `awk` in the above refers to GNU awk. See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities?answertab=votes#tab-top) if you need to install this, as well as for any other GNU utilities on macOS)

---

### 3. Using AWS CLI's `s3api`

(with either [`list-objects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html) or [`list-objects-v2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html))

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket the-bucket | jq  -r '.[] | max_by(.LastModified) | [.Key, .LastModified, .Size]|@csv'
```

Note that both of the `s3api` commands are paginated and handling the pagination is a [fundamental improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534077/what-is-the-difference-between-boto3-list-objects-and-list-objects-v2/37539994) in `v2` of the list-objects.

If the bucket has more than a 1000 objects (use `s3cmd du "s3://ons-dap-s-logs" | awk '{print $2}'` to get the number of objects), then you'll need to handle pagination of the API and make multiple calls to get back all the results since the [sort order](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html) of the returned results is `UTF-8 binary order`  and not 'Last Modified'.

---

### Performance comparison

Here is a simple performance comparison of the above three methods executed for the same bucket. For simplicity, the bucket had less than a 1000 objects. Here is the one-liner to see the execution times:

```
export bucket_name="the-bucket" && \
( \
time ( s3cmd     ls --recursive           "s3://${bucket_name}"             | awk '{print $1"T"$2","$3","$4}' | sort | tail -n 1                       ) & ; \
time ( aws s3    ls --recursive           "${bucket_name}"    --output text | awk '{print $1"T"$2","$3","$4}' | sort | tail -n 1                       ) & ; \
time ( aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "${bucket_name}"                  | jq  -r '.[] | max_by(.LastModified) | [.LastModified, .Size, .Key]|@csv' ) & ; \
time ( aws s3api list-objects    --bucket "${bucket_name}"                  | jq  -r '.[] | max_by(.LastModified) | [.LastModified, .Size, .Key]|@csv' ) &
) >! output.log
```

(`output.log` will store the last modified objects listed by each command)

The output of the above is as follows:

```
( s3cmd ls --recursive ...)      1.10s user 0.10s system 79% cpu 1.512 total
( aws s3 ls --recursive ...)     0.72s user 0.12s system 74% cpu 1.128 total
( aws s3api list-objects-v2 ...) 0.54s user 0.11s system 74% cpu 0.867 total
( aws s3api list-objects ...)    0.57s user 0.11s system 75% cpu 0.900 total
```

For the same number of objects being returned, `aws s3api` calls are appreciably more performant; however, there is the additional (scripting) complexity for dealing with the pagination of the API.

Useful link(s):
See [Leveraging s3 and s3api](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/leveraging-the-s3-and-s3api-commands/) to understand the difference between `aws s3` and `aws s3api`

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. S3 is not a database or filesystem.

However, with S3 queries you can request a list of objects that were created or modified after a certain date:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "YOURBUCKET" --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=2016-12-27][].{Key: Key}'
```

And if you want only added objects, not modified, you'll have to create custom metadata attribute, save it with object and query based on that custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`aws s3 ls s3://your-bucket --recursive | sort | tail -n 1`

This command will recursively check all files in all folders and subfolders of an S3 bucket, and return the **name** of the file most recently modified as well as the **timestamp** of that modification.

(Note, `awscli` should be installed first and configured with your AWS account info. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-configure-cli.html.)